# Sessions or Cookies for web-application?

Tags: php, ios, session

I'm developing my first web-based app (I guess you could call it that), but I'm struggling to decide between sessions and cookies.
I've got a simple login form, and I want an easy way to check if the user is logged in etc. I've used cookies in the past, but I've also heard of sessions. I've read up about them on the PHP manual, but it hasn't helped me so far.
I'm hoping to implement part of the system in an iPhone App down the road, so I'm not sure how I'll authenticate that, maybe one of these would be easier to implement?
I've looked at the other posts on here, but I'm still not clear on the pro's and con's for this situation.
Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Remember that cookies come from the client, and can be manipulated by an attacker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sessions" are arguably the most common approach.  Personally, I'd vote for "PHP sessions" unless you had a very good reason not to.

Here are a couple of links that might hel[p:

- http://tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/1/0
- http://www.phpshare.org/articles/Cookies-versus-Sessions

Comment: Thanks for the links, very useful. I was thinking of "PHP sessions", more than "sessions", sorry for my newbie-ness! I guess one small question is, can you make sessions last between visits? (Say, by a "keep me logged in" tick box)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are a means of enabling sessions, Cookies are small, take up bandwidth, and are manipulatable by both the client and an attacker.

They are a no-go for storing user-specific ''confidential'' or more delicate user information.